# T-SQL with GROUP BY, HAVING and COUNT in LINQ syntax

Tags: entity-framework, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

Im struggling converting a T-SQL query into LINQ syntax.

In T-SQL the query looks like this:

```sql
WITH FailedFiles AS 
(
  SELECT 1 AS FileExists
  FROM [FileHistory] f
  INNER JOIN [Users] u ON f.UerId = u.UserId
  GROUP by f.FileName
  HAVING SUM(CASE f.FileState WHEN 1 /*Success*/ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <= 0 
    AND SUM(CASE f.FileState WHEN 2 /*Failed*/ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
) 
SELECT COUNT(1) from FailedFiles
```

Having serious troubles converting the T-SQL above into LINQ (doesnt matter if query syntax or method syntax). Can someone give me a hint how the correct order and nesting of the LINQ query should look like?

**what the query actually does:**

I have a file history table with multiple entries for a individual file. Need to know how many *failed* files there are in total. Meaning a files never processed sucessfully (state 1) and at least once processed with an error (state 2). single files are grouped by file name. The query result is a single number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below query should work in theory. But it may fail depending on the version of Entity Framework and the Provider.

```
var count =  (from f in context.FileHistory
              join u in context.User on f.UserId equals u.UserId
              select f)
              .GroupBy(f=> f.FileName)
              .Where(g=> 
                       g.Count(i=> i.FileState == 1) <=0  &&
                       g.Count(i=> i.FileState == 2) >=1 ).Count();
```

Comment: Oh, this looks a lot easier than all my failed attempts. Never would have made it work, though.  The query works perfectly. Due to a compiler warning I was able to replace the Count() with Any(). Thanks a lot!